# Bluetooth A2DP on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth A2DP compliant headsets don't get recognized with my Samsung Galaxy Tab (T-Mobile) with Android 2.2.  I'd like to make it work.  The Samsung FAQ says that A2DP is supported.  But I've had no luck getting the Tab to recognize these any BT headsets.  Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the Samsung Bluetooth API filtered out zero class bluetooth devices resulting in detection problems (or not finding some devices). Samsung has now fixed this problem so all you have to do is upgrade the firmware on your tablet (using Kies) and that should take care of your problem.